# Way around Pagination safeguards

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

trying to scrape [this website](https://www.autoscout24.de/lst/bmw?atype=C&cy=D&desc=0&ocs_listing=include&sort=standard&ustate=N%2CU) with python/selenium but they implemented a cunning way to stop scrapers - the pagination doesn't extend past 20 pages.

If you [click this link](https://www.autoscout24.de/lst/bmw?atype=C&cy=D&desc=0&ocs_listing=include&sort=standard&ustate=N%2CU) you'll see there are 60,000 results, but 10 results per page across 20 pages doesn't give me all the data.

Any ideas on how to circumvent this safeguard?

Answer (score -1):

Well, it seems like a bug (or a feature ??) from the site. What you can do is use and combine the filters to lower the number of the results and scrap from there.